# Ecto Query consider timezone?

Tags: postgresql, timezone, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm using Ecto 3.0 and I'm not sure how Ecto use timezone in queries. Basically, I have two dates as input to be used as range in query:

```
from(u in User)
|> where([u], u.created_at >= type(^date_begin, :date))
|> where([u], u.created_at <= type(^date_end, :date))
|> Repo.all
```

My schemas are defined as utc_datetime, but I have a timezone to consider. So, based on local timezone, the query should return the correct result.

Example:

```
date_begin: 2018-02-16
created_at: 2018-02-16 01:00:00
```

Without timezone, created_at >= date_begin should be true.

But, with timezone -02:00:

```
date_begin: 2018-02-16
created_at: 2018-02-15 23:00:00 -02:00
```

And the comparison return false.

I want this last behaviour on query but I don't know what Ecto does in this situation.

Someone knows what happens in this case? Ecto consider only utc format in queries?

Comment: Ecto will do the correct thing here and convert the `DateTime` struct to use UTC before making the query. As a side note, the current Ecto version is 2.1.6. I believe you are using phoenix_ecto v3

Comment: So I can't tell from your question--did you try out some code and it wasn't working as expected?  Seems as if you should try it to see what happens.